# Why do string type appears in the else branch of the code when it was dealt in the if branch?

Tags: typescript

I was learning about [equality narrowing in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing) and the official handbook presented this function as example ([see this function in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgClQC5EBnKAJxjAHNEAfRMETAI2UoBpEBPUitTqNEbOHHzowASkQBvAFCJEMYIiKIAvNr6zFy5QHpDiAOrJEEKczgB3S%20ly5EU3ogDkgmrXeJMyKAALOAATRAQPVF84Sg9edwA6JQNUBKg4AFVsbE4AYXQyQmkAbmTlXjS4ABk7PIKi0uUAXxRcQvkyywQyCWQE3DhaIhLO4wNxgwA9AH5OiG7e-sGCXhHxsYnxmeSmhSagA)):

```
function example(x: string | number, y: string | boolean) {
  if (x === y) {
    // We can now call any 'string' method on 'x' or 'y'.
    // As x and y can only be equal if they had type string
    x.toUpperCase();
    y.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    console.log(x);     // x : string | number

    console.log(y);     // y : string | boolean
  }
}
```

We can see that in the `if` branch, both `x` and `y` have type narrowed down to `string`. That's why we can only call string methods. It should mean that the string type is fully dealt in the `if` branch and it should not appear in the `else` branch. On the contrary, if we check the type of both `x` and `y`, they still have `string` as the possible type in the `else` branch. Ideally, `string` shouldn't appear as a `type` in the `else` branch. Am I missing something or Typescript's type system is not capable enough to perform this level of narrowing at this time? Please help me to understand, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally, string shouldn't appear as a type in the else branch

Sure they could - if they're both strings, but if the strings aren't `===`.

```js
function example(x, y) {
  if (x === y) {
    // branch does not get entered into
  } else {
    console.log(typeof x); // string
    console.log(typeof y); // string
  }
}

example('foo', 'bar');
```

The narrowing you're expecting would occur if you used `typeof` checks instead, with `||` (though that wouldn't guarantee that both values would be strings in the first branch).

```
function example(x: string | number, y: string | boolean) {
  if (typeof x === 'string' || typeof y === 'string') {
  } else {
    console.log(x);
    //          ^? number
    console.log(y);
    //          ^? boolean
  }
}
```